Handling Dynamic Protobuf Messages in Rust
I'm trying to develop a Rust application using Tonic to interact with gRPC endpoints. I want to be able to send requests like grpcurl in Go. For example, with grpcurl, I can send a request like this:
grpcurl -plaintext -d @ localhost:50051 my.examples.v1.Greeter/GetGreeting <<EOF
{"test":"test"}
EOF

This lets me specify the endpoint as a string ("my.examples.v1.Greeter/GetGreeting") and send the request without relying on precompiled methods or build scripts.
In my Rust application, I want to load the protobuf definitions dynamically and let the user select and interact with the endpoints at runtime. I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle the unknown types and structures required for sending the request, as they aren't known at compile time.
How can I make this dynamic behaviour work in Rust?
In particular, how can I handle creating and sending Protobuf messages based on user input and dynamic endpoint selection without relying on precompiled structs and methods?
I've already tried retrieving the proto file via reflection, and it works fine.
I also tried rebuilding the message functions that are generated in Tonic, but I couldn't get anything working because some of the data types need to be known at compile time.

A good way to do this is to use reflection but services aren't required to support reflection and so you'll have problems. Protobuf messages can be ambiguous and so you'll be unable to determine the schema in these cases.
